# Difference between command-line tar and shutil.make_archive?

Tags: python, tar

When I generate a tar.gz file using `tar cfz cl.tar.gz Sources` as compared to the python `shutil.make_archive ( "py", "gztar", "Sources" )`, I get different results:

```
$ tar -tf cl.tar.gz | head -3
algorithm/
aligned_storage.hpp
algorithm/cxx11/


$ tar -tf py.tar.gz | head -3
./algorithm/
./aligned_storage.hpp
./algorithm/cxx11/
```

Most of the time this makes no difference; but if you pass `--strip-components` when un-tarring then the two archives behave differently.

I'd really like to get the same structure from the python code that I did from the shell script, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Mac OS 10.8.1, if that makes a difference.

Comment: On Ubuntu I get the same format for both methods (ie with `./`). How exactly are you creating the tarball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [make_archive](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) function takes two arguments, `root_dir` and `base_dir`. If you set base_dir to something else, it gets rid of the `./` prefix. For example:

```
$ tree
.
├── blah
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2

$ python
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.make_archive("test", "gztar", ".", "blah")

$ tar -tf test.tar.gz 
blah/
blah/file1
blah/file2
```

This is limited to a single directory. If you want to add more than a single directory or file like this, you will have to use the [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) module directly.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I had tried it the other way around; `shutil.make_archive ( "py", "gztar", "Sources", "." )` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) directly instead, which will allow you to encode any filename you like into the archive.